# How to use port to transfer message between main.js and the panel's content script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, messaging, firefox-addon-sdk

I encounter a problem with my firefox addon.I write code in the `main.js` like this:

```
var mypanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 322,
  height: 427,
  contentURL: data.url("main.html"),
  include:["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("js/content.js")]  
});


mypanel.on('message', function(message) {
    switch(message.type) {
      case 'type1':
        console.log(message.content);
        break;
      case 'type2':
        console.log(message.content);
        break;
     }
});
```

the code in the `content.js`:

```
self.port.emit("message",{type:"type1",content:"content1"});
```

When I run the code, the Mozilla Addon-Builder remind me that "`TypeError: self.port is undefined`",so what's wrong with my code?Or the way I write about the Firefox `port` messaging is wrong? How should I write the code? Thank you.

Comment: you'll need to give us more infos. What is self ?

Comment: Ok.the `self` is from [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Scripting Trusted Panel Content](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#Scripting%20Trusted%20Panel%20Content)

Comment: Thank you.I find the solution: change the `self` object to `addon` object.